# Parse curly brackets into a json?

Tags: python, json, api, parsing

I want to parse this json with python:

```json
[
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "74,050",
            "venta": "79,050",
            "agencia": "349",
            "nombre": "Dolar Oficial",
            "variacion": "0,030",
            "ventaCero": "TRUE",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "127,000",
            "venta": "131,000",
            "agencia": "310",
            "nombre": "Dolar Blue",
            "variacion": "0",
            "ventaCero": "TRUE",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "No Cotiza",
            "venta": "0",
            "agencia": "311",
            "nombre": "Dolar Soja",
            "variacion": "0",
            "ventaCero": "TRUE",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "119,550",
            "venta": "120,190",
            "agencia": "312",
            "nombre": "Dolar Contado con Liqui",
            "variacion": "0,730",
            "ventaCero": "TRUE",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "121,760",
            "venta": "118,280",
            "agencia": "313",
            "nombre": "Dolar Bolsa",
            "variacion": "4,560",
            "ventaCero": "TRUE",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "9.852,070",
            "venta": "10.251,516",
            "agencia": "399",
            "nombre": "Bitcoin",
            "variacion": "-0,24",
            "ventaCero": "TRUE",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "nombre": "Dolar turista",
            "compra": "No Cotiza",
            "venta": "102,77",
            "agencia": "406",
            "variacion": "0,03"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "compra": "72,56",
            "venta": "77,50",
            "agencia": "302",
            "nombre": "Dolar",
            "decimales": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "casa": {
            "nombre": "Argentina",
            "compra": "2.149,00",
            "venta": "-0,05",
            "mejor_compra": "True",
            "mejor_venta": "False",
            "fecha": "05\\/05\\/15",
            "recorrido": "16:30",
            "afluencia": {},
            "agencia": "141",
            "observaciones": {}
        }
    }
]
```

This json have curly brackets inside curly brackets too. How, for example, can I access inside first `"casa"`, and inside this first `"casa"`, access to `"compra"`, and return its value?

I did this:

```
dolarsi = requests.get('https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales').text
dolarvalue = json.loads(dolarsi)
for value in dolarvalue[0]:
    print(value)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the JSON there. That link might become invalid in the future.

Comment: `requests` has special method for JSON data `dolarvalue = requests.get(...).json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dolarvalue` you have a list of dictionaries whose keys are redundant information because they are equal (`casa`) and whose values are also dictionaries, so you have a list of nested dictionaries due to the way this JSON is structured, and this can be tricky.

Try to run this in order to visualize it:

```
import requests
import json

dolarsi = requests.get('https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales').text
dolarvalue = json.loads(dolarsi)
print("\n-----------------\n")
print(dolarvalue)
print("\n-----------------\n")
for i in dolarvalue:
    for (key, value) in i.items():
        for (key2, value2) in value.items():
            print(f"{key} : {key2} : {value2}")
        print("\n")
```

I can't provide you a concrete solution because you didn't specified what you want but I hope that this way of iterating over this structure helps you.
Try to be more precise and give more details about what you're trying to achieve in your future questions.

Please mark this question as solved if this answer has help you

Comment: Thanks but I still cannot resolve it. What i want is to access a specific value. Por example, casa > nombre > "Dolar Oficial" (only that value). If I access in this value for example, I can access other valuer from it's dictionaries.

Comment: @Sebastian in that case "nombre" will be in `key2` and "Dolar Oficial" in `value2`, just add the logic that you need

Comment: Thanks @Polo it works! Was exactly as you show me, with little bit more code I can access to my information: if 'Dolar Oficial' in value.values()